# knockout textarea value binding shows ASCII characters for line breaks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, knockout.js, textarea, knockout-validation

I have a knockout value binded textarea like so:

```
<textarea class="form-control" data-bind="value: test" name="test" rows="4"></textarea>
```

However, when saving data with line breaks or extra spaces, upon next viewing of the page it displays it with the ASCII characters. Like so:

```
Overview being explained here in this box.&#xA;&#xA;Test stuff test stuff.
```

When I look at the value in the database it does not have those characters:

> Overview being explained here in this box.
>
> Test stuff test stuff.

Indeed even in the view model before the data gets passed to the view everything looks correct:

```
Overview being explained here in this box.\n\nTest stuff test stuff.
```

And finally even when first entered, the knockout property `pageModel().test()` shows the text like this too:

> "Overview being explained here in this box.
>
> Test stuff test stuff."

So why does knockout finally render it with the ASCII characters? My KO model looks like this when the value is already input:

```
self.test = ko.observable('Overview being explained here in this box.&#xA;&#xA;Test stuff test stuff.');
```

Okay, it's an MVC issue then, because I am calling it like so:

```
self.test = ko.observable('@Model.Test');
```

But I can't figure out how to get this to work, if I use `Html.Raw` the line breaks are interpreted correctly but then that breaks the javascript breaks because there is a space between lines without proper string ending.

I also try just escaping the \r\n characters:

```
self.test = ko.observable('Overview being explained here in this box.\\n\\nTest stuff test stuff.');
```

This doesn't remove the problem though, I still get the double `&#xA;`.

How the heck can I get this working right while still using the value binding? Because I am using knockout.validation, and I could make this work by using html binding and use a slight hack:

```
<textarea class="form-control" data-bind="value: test, event: { keyup: function(data, event) { data.test(event.target.value); } }" name="test" rows="2"></textarea>
```

But this completely breaks knockout validation for any textareas because html is a one way binding that doesn't get validated. So I still need to use the value binding.

How to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
self.test = ko.observable('@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(ViewBag.Test)');
```

or as you pointed out for .NET Core you'll need

```
@(JavaScriptEncoder.Default.Encode(question.Test))
```

Comment: I'm using NET CORE so this didn't work, but this did `@(JavaScriptEncoder.Default.Encode(question.Test))`. Please update your answer to include that, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.